# Kendo MVC Cascading Dropdownlist Issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-asp.net-mvc, cascadingdropdown

I am using `Kendo UI ASP.NET MVC` and I want to do a cascading drop-down list using it. I am having problem in 3rd drop-down list which shows all values from database instead of the selected id value from second drop-down list.

My Controller Code :-

```
public ActionResult CDropdown()
{
    return View();
}
public JsonResult GetCascadeDept()
{
    return Json(db.DeptData.Select(c => new { DepartmentID = c.DepartmentID, DepartmentName = c.DepartmentName }), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

public JsonResult GetCascadeEmployee(int? Departmets)
{
    var empdata = db.EmpData.AsQueryable();
    if (Departmets != null)
    {
        empdata = empdata.Where(p => p.DepartmentID == Departmets);
    }
    return Json(empdata.Select(p => new { EmployeeID = p.EmployeeID, EmpName = p.EmpName }), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

public JsonResult GetCascadeMovies(int? Employees)
{
    var d = from c in db.EmpMovies orderby c.MovieName select c;
    var moviedata = db.EmpMovies.AsQueryable();
    if (Employees != null)
    {
        int cat = Convert.ToInt32(Employees);
        moviedata = moviedata.Where(p => p.EmployeeID == Employees);
    }
    return Json(moviedata.Select(p => new { MovieId = p.MovieId, MovieName = p.MovieName }), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

My View Code :-

```
<div>
    <p>
        <label for="Departmets">Department :- </label>
        @(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
              .Name("Departmets")
              .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:300px" })
              .OptionLabel("-- Select Department --")
              .DataTextField("DepartmentName")
              .DataValueField("DepartmentID")
              .DataSource(source =>
              {
                  source.Read(read =>
                  {
                      read.Action("GetCascadeDept", "Home");
                      //.Data("FilterDepartmets");
                  })
                  .ServerFiltering(true);
              })
              .SelectedIndex(0)
        )
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="Employees">Employee :- </label>
        @(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
              .Name("Employees")
              .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:300px" })
              .OptionLabel("-- Select Employee --")
              .DataTextField("EmpName")
              .DataValueField("EmployeeID")
              .DataSource(source =>
              {
                  source.Read(read =>
                  {
                      read.Action("GetCascadeEmployee", "Home")
                      .Data("FilterEmployees");
                  })
                  .ServerFiltering(true);
              })
              .Enable(false)
              .AutoBind(false)
              .SelectedIndex(0)
              .CascadeFrom("Departmets")
        )
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function FilterEmployees() {
                return {
                    Departmets: $("#Departmets").val()
                };
            }
        </script>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="Movies">Movie Names :- </label>
        @(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
              .Name("Movies")
              .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:300px" })
              .OptionLabel("-- Select Movie --")
              .DataTextField("MovieName")
              .DataValueField("MovieId")
              .DataSource(source =>
              {
                  source.Read(read =>
                  {
                      read.Action("GetCascadeMovies", "Home")
                      .Data("FilterMovies");
                  })
                  .ServerFiltering(true);
              })
              .Enable(false)
              .AutoBind(false)
              .SelectedIndex(0)
              .CascadeFrom("Employees")
        )

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function FilterMovies() {
                return {
                    Movies: $("#FilterMovies").val()
                };
            }
        </script>
    </p>
</div>
```

I am using Kendo UI ASP MVC Dropdown List - the 3rd Dropdown shows All Values from the Table - the ID is not getting. I don't know why it is happening. Any Solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error in your `FilterMovies` function. You want to filter the movies by the selected employee so the function should be as follows (**note** the different property name `Movies` -> `Employees`, and different $ selector `"#FilterMovies"` -> `"#Employees"`):

```
function FilterMovies() {
    return {
        Employees: $("#Employees").val()
    };
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank You So Much Sir for The Help it Works Absolutely Perfect..:) :)

Answer (score 0):

Just Changed The 3rd Dropdown List in View :-

```
<p>
    <label for="Movies">Movie Names :- </label>
    @(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
          .Name("Movies")
          .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:300px" })
          .OptionLabel("-- Select Movie --")
          .DataTextField("MovieName")
          .DataValueField("MovieId")
          .DataSource(source =>
          {
              source.Read(read =>
              {
                  read.Action("GetCascadeMovies", "Home")
                  .Data("FilterMovies");
              })
              .ServerFiltering(true);
          })
          .Enable(false)
          .AutoBind(false)
          .SelectedIndex(0)
          .CascadeFrom("Employees")
    )
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function FilterMovies() {
            return {
                Employees: $("#Employees").val()
            };
        }
    </script>
</p>
```